# Shell Script. Assign $@ or $* to variable

Tags: shell, parameters

I'm trying to assign all of the parameters to a shell script in the same way that $@ or $* works. Might be easier to explain with an example of what I am trying to do

```
if [ $# == 0 ]; then
  FIELDS="$($findfields)"
else
  FIELDS=$@
fi
#Show the fields
for field in "$FIELDS"
  do
    echo "$field"
  done
```

When I run the script with no arguments, a separate script is called and the output is as expected

```
field1
field2
field3
```

When I run the script with parameters

```
$mysrcipt.sh field1 field2 field3
```

I get the following

```
field1 field2 field3
```

How can I assign $@ to the FIELDS variable so that it works in the same way as the external script?

Many thanks

Comment: What about quoting it? `FIELDS="$@"`

Comment: That was my first thought and I still get the same result

Comment: What about removing " in for? I.e. `for field in $FIELDS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store the values so that they form an array, do:

```
FIELDS=( "$@" )
```

#### Test

```
$ cat a

if [ $# == 0 ]; then
  FIELDS="$($findfields)"
else
  FIELDS=( "$@" )
fi

#Show the fields
for field in "${FIELDS[@]}"
  do
    echo "$field"
  done

$ ./a a b c
a
b
c

$ ./a "a b c"
a  b c
```

Comment: Correct answer. Do note that not all shells support the `=(…)` syntax – but recent versions of AT&T ksh93, mksh, GNU bash, zsh do. In Korn Shell, you can also write `set -A FIELDS -- "$@"`.